# Scanner with custom Delimiter to parse both Doubles and Strings?

Tags: java

Given String `1.5 + 2`, I would like to parse and handle the Double, operator, and Integer.

The below code works as expected for Strings which do not contain decimals, but for the given input it prints:

`1
.
5
+
2`

While I'd like it to print:

`1.5
+
2`

Is this possible using the the Scanner class with a custom regex?

```
String delimiter = "(?:\\s+)|(?<=[+)|(?=[+])";

Scanner scanner = new Scanner("1.5 + 2");
scanner.useDelimiter(delimiter);

while (scanner.hasNext()) {
  String token = scanner.next();
  System.out.println(token);
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason you aren't using a space as a delimiter?

Comment: Yes, i should have specified. If the input is "1.5+2" it should still print 1.5, +, 2.

Comment: I think you should design your own [RDP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser) that would handle white spaces.

Comment: @ab11 are you still looking for a better answer here?

Comment: nah. gave up, wrote my own parser

Answer (score 0):

*<strike>steals</strike> acquires ideas from [intboolstring's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38166347/scanner-with-custom-delimiter-to-parse-both-doubles-and-strings#comment63760353_38166347)* Well, why not cut the input from whitespace?

```
String delimiter = "\\s+";
```

Explanation: The above string is the regex `\s+` which matches one or more spaces/tabs/newlines.

Comment: I should have specified, it should parse regardless of whitespace. If the input is "1.5+2" it should still print 1.5, +, 2.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing a pattern for where to split (for `split()` or `Scanner`), it might be easier to just write a pattern for what you want to keep together.

Example:

```
Pattern exprPattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?" +     // digits [ '.' digits ]
                                     "|\\.\\d+" +              // '.' digits
                                     "|[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*" + // identifier
                                     "|\\S");                  // any single non-whitespace
String expr = "1.5 + 7.2*(var3 - .1)";
for (Matcher m = exprPattern.matcher(expr); m.find(); )
    System.out.println(m.group());
```

*Output*

```
1.5
+
7.2
*
(
var3
-
.1
)
```

Comment: makes sense. though, at this point, I think it might be easier to just write some parsing logic with String.charAt()?